# Show parent user site affiliation in SE chat user popup

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, stackexchange-2.0, favicon

On user profiles on chat.stackexchange.com, there's a line that shows the parent user, with the favicon of the chosen site. Can that icon be included somewhere in the popup shown when the user's gravatar is clicked as well?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because we all need a little pick-me-up on a Monday... reload and it should be there.